# Reading Excel checkbox values in Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, checkbox, apache-poi, jexcelapi

I have spent countless hours trying to find a solution to this. I have tried Apache POI, JExcel and JXLS but no where have I found code to successfully read checkbox (form control) values.

If anyone has found a working solution then it would be great if you could share it here. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have written code that reads the checkbox but it cannot determine whether it is checked or not.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.HSSFEventFactory;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.HSSFListener;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel.HSSFRequest;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.CommonObjectDataSubRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.ObjRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.Record;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.SubRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class App {
    private static final String path = "C:\\test.xls";
    private static final String Workbook = "Workbook";

    private static void readExcelfile() {
        FileInputStream file = null;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

            // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            // file.close();
            // FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
            // new File(path));
            // workbook.write(out);
            // out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (file != null)
                    file.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void readCheckbox() {
        FileInputStream file = null;
        InputStream istream = null;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(file);
            istream = poifs.createDocumentInputStream(Workbook);
            HSSFRequest req = new HSSFRequest();
            req.addListenerForAllRecords(new EventExample());
            HSSFEventFactory factory = new HSSFEventFactory();
            factory.processEvents(req, istream);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (file != null)
                    file.close();
                if (istream != null)
                    istream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ReadExcelFile");
        readExcelfile();
        System.out.println("ReadCheckbox");
        readCheckbox();
    }
}

class EventExample implements HSSFListener {

    public void processRecord(Record record) {
        switch (record.getSid()) {
        case ObjRecord.sid:
            ObjRecord objRec = (ObjRecord) record;
            List<SubRecord> subRecords = objRec.getSubRecords();
            for (SubRecord subRecord : subRecords) {
                if (subRecord instanceof CommonObjectDataSubRecord) {
                    CommonObjectDataSubRecord datasubRecord = (CommonObjectDataSubRecord) subRecord;
                    if (datasubRecord.getObjectType() == CommonObjectDataSubRecord.OBJECT_TYPE_CHECKBOX) {
                        System.out.println("ObjId: "
                                + datasubRecord.getObjectId() + "\nDetails: "
                                + datasubRecord.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you paste your code and let know the issue we may help you to figure things up. I myself prefer Apache POI.

Comment: I am trying to read Excel form controls in Java. Unfortunately, I have not made any progress on this.

Comment: Removed tags from the title.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but I ran into the same. I found a trick to determine the checkbox state.

In your example you ar looping over the SubRecords and you examine the `CommonObjectDataSubRecord`. But the value for the checkbox can be found in the one of the `SubRecord.UnknownSubRecord`. This is unfortunately a private class so you cannot call any method on it, but the `toString()` reveals the data, and with a little regex the value can be found. So using the code below I managed to retrieve the state of the checkbox:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[sid=0x000A.+?\\[0(\\d),");
if (!(subRecord instanceof CommonObjectDataSubRecord)) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(subRecord.toString());
    if (m.find()) {
        String checkBit = m.group(1);
        if (checkBit.length() == 1) {
            boolean checked = "1".equals(checkBit);
            checkBox.setChecked(checked);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my challenge is to retrieve the checkbox value in a xlsx file...

Comment: This is awfully hacky and likely to break in future versions of POI. You would be *much* better off patching that UnknownSubRecord structure and then proposing this patch on [POI's bugtracker](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI) so others can benefit from your findings as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will patch this.